# Preposition of manner (in/on/with/by)

Tags: prepositions

I came across all these sentences in which different prepositions are used to describe the same meaning

1) Wrote it in pencil ( using a pencil)
2) She played a tune on her guitar (using a guitar)
3) I want to do payment by/in cash (using cash)

My question is how do we know when to choose which?
I would be really thankful if anyone could explain this☺️

Comment: As a learner: The only way is to practice, and also practice, and then finally again practice! There might be some hints to make the practice more tractable though. Like categorizing the prepositions as place adverbs, reason adverbs, .... etc, but at the end of the day, it all boils down to putting those words into practice and memorizing them.